# align h4 tag with button on an overlay color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Boostrap 3. I am having some problems hitting my final design that should look like the below picture(notice the blue line is just to illustrate that the text should align with the button):
[image: Final desing]

I have made the banner with the headline "High servicelevel and quality", which is working fine. But I cannot figure out how to set in the subline "Book a meeting and lets find a solution".

Here is what I made until now:

[Demosite before add subtext](http://vouzalis.dk/stack.html)

[Demosite after add subtext](http://vouzalis.dk/stack-after-text.html)

When I set in the subline, the dark overlay area is getting more height, which result in a big padding between letters, and the text is not aligning with the button.

My question is how I can make the headline and subline align like the above picture?

```css
    body {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    div {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    .flexbox-column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction:column; /*Stack flex items verically*/
    }
    .flexbox-column .cta {
      margin-top: auto !important; /*Send button to bottom*/
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }
    .index-content .cta {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .index-content .cta:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }
    /* Set width between block elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }

    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .margin_bottom {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .card-img-bottom {
      color: #fff;
      height: 20rem;
      background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .img-responsive { 
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Button Position */
    .centered {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 16px;
    }

    .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }

    .inner-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      background: none;
    }
    /* Set full width on columns */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .img-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        }
        .index-content .card img {
        height: 100%
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;

      }
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .card {
        position: relative;
      }
      .card-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
      .card-content h4,
      .card-content p {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
      }
      .card-content a {
        float: right;
      }
      .index-content .card h4,
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 0 20px 15px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .card-content-textbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        /*right: 0;*//* top position on right*/
        margin: 15px;
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 91%
      }
    }

/* Grid with different placement of position buttons */
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
}

.btn-default {
  background-color:transparent;
  border:1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Full width Banner -->
 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/87/bf/cf/87bfcfb36780c0fec472d8d301be7a1c.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>HIGH SERVICELEVEL AND QUALITY</h4>
                        
                        <a href="#" class="cta">Læs Mere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try line-height

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But that will not make the text align with the button - also on viewport `<768px`.

Comment: let's say your button height is 20px; and you want a gap on both top and bottom of the button, you can use margin-top 10px and margin-bottom 10px and similarly you can set line-height of the text to 40px

Comment: @MK-DK you have to give width:auto to that bottom h4 tag not above h4 tag

Comment: @MK-DK here is the working codepen for your problem 
https://codepen.io/ruchitaghodasara/pen/QBaqLw

Comment: Thanks. I can see between `< 991px` and `> 768px` the overlay color is getting very big. But else that could be a solution.

Comment: are you open to a different solutions or do you want to use your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper around your heading and description and use flexbox to align the items, e.g.

```css
   body {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .flexbox-column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction:column; /*Stack flex items verically*/
    }
    .flexbox-column .cta {
      margin-top: auto !important; /*Send button to bottom*/
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }
    .index-content .cta {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .index-content .cta:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }
    /* Set width between block elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }

    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .margin_bottom {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .card-img-bottom {
      color: #fff;
      height: 20rem;
      background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .img-responsive { 
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Button Position */
    .centered {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 16px;
    }

    .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }

    .inner-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      background: none;
    }
    
    .card-content {
      display: flex;
      padding: 30px 0px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }
    
    .card-content__info {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      left: 3em;
      position: relative;
      /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    }
    
    .card-content__info > h4 {
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 5px 0 !important;
    }
    /* Set full width on columns */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .img-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        }
        .index-content .card img {
        height: 100%
      }

      .index-content .cta {
         width: 100px;
         padding: 12px 0px;
         margin: 25px 0 0 0;
       }

       .card-content__info {
           flex-direction: column;
           left: 0;
        }

        .card-content {
            flex-direction: column;
            left: 40px;
            position: relative;
            align-items: inherit;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;

      }
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .card {
        position: relative;
      }
      .card-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
      .card-content h4,
      .card-content p,
      .card-content span {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
      }
      .card-content a {
        float: right;
      }
      .index-content .card h4,
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 0 20px 15px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .card-content-textbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        /*right: 0;*//* top position on right*/
        margin: 15px;
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 91%
      }
    }

/* Grid with different placement of position buttons */
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
}

.btn-default {
  background-color:transparent;
  border:1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Full width Banner -->
 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/87/bf/cf/87bfcfb36780c0fec472d8d301be7a1c.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="card-content__info">
                          <h4>HIGH SERVICELEVEL AND QUALITY</h4>
                        <span>Book a meeting and let's find a solution</span>  
                        </div>         
                        <a href="#" class="cta">Læs Mere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That seems to be a nice solution. I just made a test of it here: http://vouzalis.dk/blue.html. How is it possible I can get the button more down in the right corner, and the button is not getting double size on `< 768px`?

Comment: You can use `align-items: flex-end` property to align the button below. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you again. It is not working `< 768 px`: http://vouzalis.dk/blue.html

Comment: If you want to make the button larger on devices with 768px or less, you'd need to modify the @media (max-width: 768px) and adjust the width and vertical padding of `.index-content .cta` (I modified the answer and showed an example)

Comment: I like this solution I can see. The text and button align perfectly. But `< 768px` I would do anything to get the button to jump down like this: http://vouzalis.dk/serg.html. How is that possible? I would like yo use your code. Or maybe like this: https://ibb.co/d1pBUT ?

Comment: You are the king. Thank you a lot, this solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your button in a different div, to be at the same level as the "card" div. Apply the class "float-left" to the card div and "float-right" to the new div.

Also, you display: inline-block; if needed, not sure if the classes mentioned above have it by default.

After doing this, you can check the line-height of your h4 and set it to 1. and adjust the rest of the content according to the design.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If you have time I would love to see an example of your suggestion. I am not quite sure how to organize that code

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: Thank you a lot. Yes it is. There is missing the subline, but it seems that can be put in. But `< 768 px` the text is only taking half width. I dont understand that? But could be a nice solution if the column size could be fixed somehow?

Comment: If you look at the css, I put  the width of the "card" class to 70%. You can play with that under 768, make it bigger or smaller, whichever suits your design better.

Comment: Also you can make the font size of the h4 smaller when under 768 for better UX.

Comment: This is actually a good solution I think. I tried your code and suggestion here: http://vouzalis.dk/serg.html. What do you think? The only thing I need is to get the "HIGH SERVICELEVEL AND QUALITY" down, so it is closer to the text: "HERE IS A LONG SUBLINE TEXT WITH COLOURS" on `> 768px`. I can see there is a `20px margin`. If I overwrite that, it does not look how I want. I would like to stick to your suggestion.

Comment: keep it both outside the media query and inside too. So when it is over 768px it takes the normal styling and when it goes below, the media query will overwrite it.

Comment: Hm dont understand, sorry. I can set `.index-content .card h4, .index-content .card p {padding: 5px}`. Then the text is fitting, but the text is not aligning with the button then.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the media query width:100% is coming just change that width:100% to width:auto it will work fine. css code is given below

and another solution is

you could wrap your heading div in one div and give them float left and for button give float right and in outer div give clearfix class 
For first solution css is

```
    @media (min-width: 768px)
        .card-content h4, .card-content p {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }

        <div class="card-content clearfix">
                                <div style="float:left">
<h4>HIGH SERVICELEVEL AND QUALITY</h4>
                                <h4>BOOK A MEETING AND LETS FIND A SOLUTION</h4>
</div>
                                <a href="#" class="cta" style="float:right">Læs Mere</a>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. On my side of the screen this is not solving the problem.

Comment: I just made a demo og your suggestion. When you minimize the window it is not rendering very nicely: http://vouzalis.dk/rg.html

Comment: @MK-DK: here is the working codepen https://codepen.io/ruchitaghodasara/pen/QBaqLw